# Finding a matrix projecting vectors onto column space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I can't find $P$, for vectors you can do $P = A(A^{T}A)^{-1}A^T$. But here its not working because  matrices have dimensions that can't multiply or divide. help

[image]

Comment: Perform the multiplications in your formula.

Comment: i told u that they can't multiply because A^TA is a 2 x 2 while AA^t is a 3 x 3 matrix

Comment: Why do you care about $AA^T$? It doesn't appear anywhere in the formula for $P$.

Comment: Thanks, our professor had re-arranged the formular to be;   (A^tA)^-1* (AA^t)   which worked for vectors, but has been giving me errors for matrices. THANKS

Answer (score 2):

The dimensions of the matrices do match.

Matrix $A$ is 3x2, which matches with $(A^TA)^{-1}$, which is 2x2.

The result $A(A^TA)^{-1}$ is again 3x2.

When multiplying it with $A^T$, which is 2x3, you get a 3x3 matrix for $P$.

Comment: THNK-YOU very much for your synthesis, I wasn't following the order